# Show project only if owner or member

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In the project management app I'm working on I want it only to be possible to show a project if the user is admin of the project or a member of the project.

The view below doesn't (of course) work, but it shows one way of checking if the user is admin of the project. One way I know of how to check whether a user is a member or not is by using the following query:

```
projects = get_list_or_404(Project.objects.filter(users__id__iexact=request.user.id))
```

...though I have no idea of how to use these (if they should be used) ways of checking if the user has permission to view the project for this purpose, and not give access if that is not the case.

How could this be done?

**view:**

```
@login_required
def show_project(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk = project_id)
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(project_id = project_id)

    if project.owned_by_user(request.user):
         ???
    elsif

    else:
        message = "You don't have permission to the project"

    return render(request, 'projects/show.html', {"project" : project, "tickets" : tickets, "message": message})
```

**model:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...other fields...
    added_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projects')  <-- members

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def owned_by_user(self, user):
        return self.added_by_user == user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Have a play around with this code - should give you some ideas -

```
@login_required
def show_project(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk = project_id)
    tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(project_id = project_id)
    if request.user in project.users.all or project.owned_by_user(request.user):
        return render(request, 'projects/show.html', {"project" : project, "tickets" : tickets})
    else:
        return render(request, 'projects/show.html', {"error_message": "You don't have permission to view the project"})
```

Then in your template

```
{% if error_message %}
    <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
{% else %}
   {% for ticket in tickets %}
        <p>{{ ticket }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
    <div>{{ project }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, implementing your solution throws the following error: "argument of type 'ManyRelatedManager' is not iterable" on this line: 'if request.user in project.users or project.owned_by_user(request.user):' ?

Comment: it should be project.users.all()