# Prevent the creator of a project to become a member of the project

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When you create a project in the app I'm working on it's possible to choose which users should become members of the project. However, I don't want the creator (to be admin) of the project to be on the list of users that you can choose to become members.

Either you are an admin OR a member, not both. Of course it's possible by not adding one self as a member, but I don't even want it to be possible.

How could this be done?

**view:**

```
def project_add(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.date_added = datetime.date.today()
        form.instance.date_updated = datetime.date.today()
        form.instance.added_by_user = request.user
        form.save()
        return redirect(project_list)
else:
    form = ProjectForm()

return render(request, 'projects/add.html', {"form" : form})
```

**project model:**

```
class Project(models.Model):
...rest of the fields...
added_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projects')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

def owned_by_user(self, user):
    return self.added_by_user == user
```

**the form:**

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Project
    exclude = ('date_added', 'date_updated', 'added_by_user')
```

...

To make it more clear I've provided an image below. I don't want "Nisse" to be possible to choose under "Users:" below (which is the members of the project), because Nisse is the user who is creating the project.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show project only if owner or member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232954/show-project-only-if-owner-or-member)

Comment: How are you adding `project.users`? Just prevent the `added_by_user` from being added to `users` with something like: `If project.owned_by_user(request.user): return "You cannot add yourself as a user to a project you own"; else: users = request.user`

Comment: @Hedde: No, that's definitely not a duplicate because it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @DanHoerst: That solution will still make it possible to choose the user in the list of users in the template, right? Is it possible to render out the select box without the creator of the project from the beginning?

Comment: Render out what select box? You haven't given much information here.

Comment: No you're right, my bad. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm): 
    ...
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    # change the queryset for the modelform `users` field to exclude `instance.added_by_user`
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['users'].queryset = self.fields['users'].queryset.exclude(self.instance.added_by_user)

    # custom clean method to not allow the `added_by_user`
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProjectForm, self).clean()
        if self.instance.added_by_user in cleaned_data.get('users'):
            raise ValidationError("OH NOES")
        return cleaned_data
```

you may need to massage this a bit. its untested but you get the idea

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I need to import something? I get "Exception Type: DoesNotExist"...

Comment: you probably need `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError` and `django.forms` not really sure what your error is without more stack trace.